# ActionScript vs Java detect collision

Tags: java, actionscript, collision-detection

I am trying to built a simple game in Java.In Flash/Actionscript in order to detect object collision you just use `Object1.hitTestObject(Object2)`.Is there similar way in Java?

Comment: What library are you using to draw objects?

Comment: http://beginwithjava.blogspot.com/2010/08/simple-collision-detection-in-java.html and http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/collision/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using a game engine, like [JGame](http://www.borisvanschooten.nl/13thmonkey/~boris/jgame/) or similar, that includes collision detection built-in. The Java core libraries do not contain collision detection.